# Проблема при сборке проекта на .NET 6.0: "The MonoGame content tools only work on a 64bit OS"

Tags: c#, .net, monogame, dotnet-cli

У меня 32-битная ОС. Я взял готовую команду для сборки проекта из сайта MonoGame. При выполнении команды высвечивается текст, что инструменты MonoGame работают только на 64-битных ОС.

Как мне исправить проблему, если у меня нет возможности поменять ОС на 64-битную? Расскажите, пожалуйста, про альтернативы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте сначала предлагался вариант с использованием Visual Studio 2022 и позднее и расширения MonoGame, но проблема в том, что мой компьютер не может поддерживать его.

У меня стоит Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Я вам говорил альтернативы - Rider (ломанная версия есть) и VS Code (по сути блокнот на стероидах), они относительно легкие. Касательно ошибки, собрать вы в теории можете под x64, достаточно указать в команде не `x86`, а `x64`, либо [в конфигурации проекта](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2022#manually-editing-the-project-file) настраивать (FW мог, как .NET не знаю). НО, вы не сможете у себя запустить этот проект, а значит без отладки и прочего. И тут как бы вопрос, а оно вам нужно такое?

Comment: _нет возможности поменять ОС на 64-битную_ ...скомпилить сможете, запустить - нет.

Comment: Скомпилировать не получается; требует 64-битную ОС.

Comment: Значит в .NET эту возможность убрали, билдер .NET Framework это умел. Тогда у вас нет вообще вариантов, советую поставить х64 винду...